# How to measure the dollar-amount cost of script execution?

Tags: cloud, computation

Let's say I have an EC2 instance with 1 core that costs me $1/hour. Is it accurate to say that if the execution time of the script is 0.006 seconds then cost of running that script once would be $0.0001?

If not, what better methods and metrics exist to measure this cost accurately?